# php recursive function to print a string 3 times does not work

Tags: php, recursion

Let's say we have a string "Hello, PHP" and we want to repeat it
three times using a recursive function.

So I've tried this:

```
$initialString = "Hello, PHP";
$myFunc = function(&$myFunc, $n = 3, $initialString){
    if($n >= 0){
        $temp = $myFunc($myFunc, $n - 1, $initialString);
        $initialString .= ", " . $initialString;
        return $temp;
    }

    return $initialString;
};
```

It doesn't work, and I can't print it.

Comment: What does "doesn't work mean"? Pleas be specific and read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried `echo $myFunc`?

Answer (score 1):

the issue with your recursive attempt is that you are invoking the recursion function before applying your modification on your variable,

when $n = 3 , you will pass the recursion base `if($n >= 0){` and immediately you will invoke the recursive function again before any modification on the `$initialstring`.

so `$n = 2` now, the recursion base will be passed, and again before any modification in the `$initialstring` you will return the recursive function which will still do the same behavior until it return the `$initialstring` ***without any modification***.

all what you need in your case is to move the `$initialString .= ", " . $initialString;` before your recursion invoking.

```
$initialString = "Hello, PHP";
$myFunc = function(&$myFunc, $n = 3, $initialString){
    if($n >= 0){
        $initialString .= ", " . $initialString;
        $temp = $myFunc($myFunc, $n - 1, $initialString);
        return $temp;
    }

    return $initialString;
};
```

Live example: https://3v4l.org/Aa2Rd

*note that, in this case you will not get the string "Hello, PHP" 3 times, that's because you are recurse the **concatenation** of your string modification*

Answer (score 0):

Few issues.

You check for >= 0 before taking 1 from the passed counter, so the routine repeats 4 times.

You manipulate the string after calling the function, but after that you do nothing with the string. If you manipulate the string before the call then you land up adding items more quickly (as you pass the string repeated, then repeat the repeated string, etc)

Possibly the following will do it for you, returning nothing if it has already exceeded the count.

```
$initialString = "Hello PHP";
$myFunc = function($n = 3, $initialString) use (&$myFunc) {
    if($n > 0){
        $temp = $initialString . "," . $myFunc($n - 1, $initialString);
        return $temp;
    }

    return '';
};

echo $myFunc(3, $initialString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
$initialString = "Hello, PHP";
$n=3;
function printtr($initialString, $n)
{
    if ($n==0)
    {
        exit;
    }
    echo $initialString."<br/>";
    $n = $n-1;
    printtr($initialString, $n);
}
printtr($initialString, $n);
```

Comment: "Please try this" answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Every answer, without exception, should include a plain English explanation of how the suggested solution works and why you feel it is good advice.